# append list with for loop and get multiple values in each cell in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, append

I'm trying to run 3 optimization with for loop and store the results in one dataframe.

After each optimization (element of the for loop), I append lists of results and being able to get all the reults in one list. However, when I try to convert the list to dataframe, I get one row for each of the optimization and multiple values in each cell corresponding to the variable name and the optimization number like this:

```
Date = []
results = []


for idx, df in enumerate([df0,df1,df2]):

    model = ConcreteModel()
    
    model.T = Set(initialize=df.hour.tolist(), ordered=True)

...


    # Solve model
    solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
    solver.solve(model) 
    
    Date = list(df['Date'])
    results.append([Date, model.Ein.get_values().values(), model.Eout.get_values().values(), 
                    model.Z.get_values().values(), model.NES.get_values().values(), 
                    model.L.get_values().values()])
    
df_results = pd.DataFrame(results)
df_results.rename(columns = {0: 'Date', 1: 'Ein', 2:'Eout', 3:'Z', 4:'NES', 5:'L'}, inplace = True)
df_results

## The output of the df is:

                                              Date                                              Ein                         
0   [2019-01-01, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-0...   (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, ...   (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...   (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, ...   (0.0, 0.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, 0.0, -100.0...   (16231.0, 16051.0, 15806.0, 15581.0, 15610.0, ...
1   [2019-01-16, 2019-01-16, 2019-01-16, 2019-01-1...   (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...   (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...   (0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, ...   (0.0, -100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, -100.0, -10...   (17643.0, 18654.0, 20462.0, 20448.0, 20305.0, ...
2   [2019-01-31, 2019-01-31, 2019-01-31, 2019-01-3...   (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...   (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, ...   (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, ...   (0.0, 0.0, -100.0, 0.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0...   (22155.0, 22184.0, 21510.0, 21193.0, 20884.0, ...


#The output of the list named results is:

[[['2019-01-01',
   '2019-01-01',
   '2019-01-01',
...
   '2019-01-15',
   '2019-01-15',
   '2019-01-15',
   '2019-01-15',
   '2019-01-15',
   '2019-01-15',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16'],
  dict_values([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
...
-1.11022302462516e-16, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.11022302462516e-16, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.333333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.666666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
  dict_values([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 
...
0.333333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.833333333333333, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.166666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625, 0.00048828125, 0.0]),
  dict_values([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 
...
0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625, 0.00048828125, 0.00048828125]),
 [['2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
   '2019-01-16',
...


Is it because each result in the for loop has de different dictionary? How could my results in this form:

       Date       Ein   Eout   Z   NES        L                                                     
0   2019-01-01    1.0   0.0   1.0 -100.0  16231.0
1   2019-01-01    1.0   1.0   0.0  100.0  16051.0,  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're constantly appending to `results` creating a list of lists of the wrong dimension. I hope this solution works for you -

```py
df_results  = pd.DataFrame(zip(Date, model.Ein.get_values().values(), model.Eout.get_values().values(), 
                    model.Z.get_values().values(), model.NES.get_values().values(), 
                    model.L.get_values().values()))
```

Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With zip, it return the correct format for the dataframe but the problem is that it returns values only for the last argument of the for loop which is ``` for idx, df in enumerate([df0,df1,df2]):  ``` df2 in this case.